# How to Copy Library between python installations

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

Here is the situation:

- **Raspberry pi 2** running **raspbian** running python 3.5.2 with **Opencv,Numpy,pyusb**
- **Orange pi pc** running Armbian.
  Both boards are quad-core arm.

So the question is can i somehow transfer the libraries from one distro to another without recompiling them? It would save me hours.

If not can i just transfer Opencv as this is the main culprit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt it, honestly. But maybe?

Comment: You can download a precompiled library from the repository so maybe something similar could be done.